# PowerApps - Log In with a User Level Access (Custom Login Screen)

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I want to create a custom login form with several conditions.

Here is the scenario:
When users log in to the app, PowerApps only show the screen based on their position.
for example:

- Mr. ABC as a Staff,
- Mrs. DEF as a Supervisor,
- then when Mr. ABC logs in, he just gets a Staff screen
- and when Mrs. DEF logs in, she can access to Staff and Supervisor
  screen

I already create a table on Data Source with Name, Email, Password and Position column.
On Canvas App:

- I set TextInput1 (Email)
- TextInput2 (Password)
- and button1 (Login)

On button1:
I set a function on OnSelect event

```
If(LookUp('MyDataSource', Email = TextInput1.Text, Password)=TextInput2.Text, Nagivate(StaffScreen,None))
```

This action is just only taken users to Staff Screen.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Currently it looks like you have no condition to navigate to a staff and supervisor screen.

Answer (score 0):

A Suggestion:
You can setup/create different groups for each category of users in Azure AD and use AD connector to valid each user and navigate them to appropriate screens.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid managing a table of passwords, etc. This adds unnecessary complexity. Users already have to use their Active Directory credentials to log *into* PowerApps. Leverage Active Directory attributes or Microsoft Office properties.

One way is to key off of the `JobTitle` listed in Microsoft Office, you can accomplish this with the [`Office365Users` Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-office365-users) in PowerApps.

`OnStart`:

```
Set(varJobTitle, 
    First(
        Office365Users.SearchUserV2(
            {
                searchTerm:User().Email
            }
        ).value.JobTitle
    ).JobTitle
)
```

`OnSelect` of a "Login" button on the first screen:

```
If(
    varJobTitle = "Staff",
    Set(varUserType, "user");
    Navigate(scrStaff, Fade),
    varJobTitle = "Supervisor",
    Set(varUserType, "admin");
    Navigate(scrSupervisors, Fade)
    <etc.>
)
```

You could adapt this to groups of `JobTitles` as well with something like:

```
If(
    Or(
        varJobTitle = "Staff",
        varJobTitle = "Helper",
        varJobTitle = "Deckhand"
    ),
    Set(varUserType, "user");
    Navigate(scrStaff, Fade),
    Or(
        varJobTitle = "Supervisor",
        varJobTitle = "Manager",
        varJobTitle = "Director"
    ),
    Set(varUserType, "admin");
    Navigate(scrSupervisors, Fade)
    <etc.>
)
```

- Then on `scrSupervisors`, add a button that navigates admins to `scrStaff`.
- Then on `scrStaff` add a button with `Visible` property set to `If(varUserType = "admin", true, false)` which navigates admins to `scrSupervisors`.

Many ways to accomplish what you're aiming for. Adapt accordingly.